# QComboBox:focus Qt Style Sheet

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I have an *editable* combo box on the input form, which background must change when it receives focus. The following code works perfect for QLineEdit but has no effect on QComboBox.

```
QLineEdit, QComboBox { background-color: green; }
QLineEdit:focus, QComboBox:focus { background-color: red; }
```

Is it possible to make QComboBox behaves as expected like QLineEdit **using only Qt style sheets**?

Comment: try QComboBox:!editable:focus

Comment: Great question! I was able to get somewhere with `setStyleSheet("QLineEdit, QComboBox { background-color: green; }"
                            "QComboBox:focus, QComboBox:focus QListView  { background-color: red; }");` but it seems that I am missing something...

Comment: Even setting this works, but not the background `setStyleSheet("QLineEdit, QComboBox { background-color: green; }"
                            "QComboBox:focus, QComboBox:focus QAbstractItemView  { background-color: red; selection-background-color: red}");`

Comment: @RachelGallen I already tried it before asking here.

Comment: @NemanjaBoric: Yes, I tried it too, but it changes only the background color of selected text. Also, when I use `QComboBox { background-color: transparent; }` my `:focus` starts to work, but I lose my out-of-focus background. Putting `padding: 2` gives some additional information - there is somthing in front of the combo box. It should be `QLineEdit`, but it's not, or not exactly. I tried `QComboBox > QLineEdit` without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to do this by subclassing QLineEdit, and installing it into the combo box (with `QComboBox::setLineEdit()`).  Then, override the focusIn() and focusOut() functions of QLineEdit, and set a style sheet with the appropriate background color in those functions.

Another way would be to install an event handler on the combo box, (and/or its associated QLineEdit) and trap focus in/out events, and change the style sheet then.

Comment: Your are probably right, but it changes the code of the program. My question was not quite correct. I already have such kind of solution, and it is simpliest: to put the `QComboBox` inside a `QFrame`, with apropriate background and set `QComboBox { background-color: transparent; }`. I will clarify my question.